Unable to Edit or Add Photo Gallery Under Portfolio in WordPress 6.2.5
I'm experiencing an issue with editing or adding a photo gallery for our projects under the Portfolio section in WordPress 6.2.5.
Details:
WordPress Version: 6.2.5
Plugin Version: 1.8.58 (lightbox plugin)
I have attempted the following troubleshooting steps:
Created a new gallery but still it didn't work
Updated the lightbox plugin to the latest version.
Despite these efforts, I am still unable to make changes to the existing gallery or add new photos. Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can provide guidance on how to resolve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

You may want to ask the Lightbox developers for assistance with this.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
